# Eureka Swift ViewRow - UIButton will not click

Tags: swift, uiview, eureka-forms

ok I added this btnPhoto to this UIView in [Eureka Communities ViewRow](https://github.com/EurekaCommunity/ViewRow) but it is unclickable? (`ViewControllerEdit.photoClicked(_:)` never fires) any notion why this is?

```
       form.last! <<< ViewRow<UIView>() { (row) in }.cellSetup { (cell, row) in
                    row.title = _title
                    row.tag = _dataname
                    row.value = _default

                    let vwWidth: CGFloat = (self.tableView?.frame.width)!
                    print("vwWidth: \(vwWidth)") //<-- this proves it is not 0 wide
                    cell.view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:  0, width: vwWidth, height: 65))

                    row.cellSetup({ (cell, row) in
                        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = Globals.Color_SlateTextBox()
                        cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = Globals.Color_Blue()
                        cell.tintColor = Globals.Color_BackgroundSilver()
                        row.cell.height = {
                            return  65
                        }
                    }).cellUpdate({ (cell, row) in
                        cell.textLabel?.textColor = Globals.Color_Blue()
                    })

                    let btnPhoto = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x:180, y:0, width:180, height:40))
                    btnPhoto.setTitle("Take Photo",for: .normal)
                    btnPhoto.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewControllerEdit.photoClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

                    cell.view!.addSubview(btnPhoto)
                }
```

i've also tried `cell.viewContent.addSubView()` it makes no difference

does anyone know why the `addTarget` fails to fire?

Comment: Can you cast the cell as a specific kind of cell (that you implemented) which has a delegate type of a specific protocol which your ViewController conforms to. Then in an action method of the cell class, call the delegate's desired function to fire. I dont know about this repo, but just have this idea.

Comment: I kinda of follow what you mean.. but only kind of. I think the issue is I might be casting a UIView into a UIView Container.. which might be not the point..

Comment: `oh wow I just seen it` I put this in there (that CRIMINALLY I didn't share) `row.baseCell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` was in there somewhere.. it was  cut and paste error... so sorry.. the is the bool to disable the user doing anything

Comment: Sorry, just found your Twitter message.  Looks like you've found the cause of the problem.  Setting `isUserInteractionEnabled` to false would definitely prevent clicks from working.